# User configurable TCP stream with Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to set up a TCP stream to a client using node.js where the user can specify the data host and port. I am using socket.io to create a socket connection to the client and net.createConnection to establish the stream. Once the stream is established I need to send the data from the stream to the client socket. The code I have works except in the case of the client changing the host and/or data socket. It seems once the client socket is established then I can change the port or host on the TCP stream. The socket message is received and the values for host and port make it to the right spot. But no joy, the data from the TCP stream is not connected and it seems the .on(error), .on(connect),  etc don't work. Am I having a scope issue? The implied scope in the code block below is how I currently have it set up. Any bones you can toss my way will make the dog happy. I am in a hole and can't seem to get out.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express.createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: false }),
    host = "somehost",
    port = 2001,
    dataStream = net.createConnection(port, host);


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){


    dataStream.on('error', function(error){
        socket.emit('error',{message:"Data Connection Error "+ error});
    });

    dataStream.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('connected',{message:"Data Source Connected"});
    });

    dataStream.on('data', function(data) {  
        socket.emit(buffer);
    }); 

    // Handle Client request to change stream 
    socket.on('message',function(data) {
            var clientMessage = JSON.parse(data);       
            for(var key in clientMessage) {
                switch (key){
                    case "connectString":{
                        if(clientMessage[key].dataHost !== "" && clientMessage[key].dataPort !== ""){
                            //create new net connection
                            dataStream.end();
                            dataStream = net.createConnection(clientMessage[key].dataPort,clientMessage[key].dataHost);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index.html);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You're replacing the `datastream` object with a new tcp connection. You have to reattach your `datastream` event handlers after `dataStream = net.createConnection` in the `connectString` case.

Comment: Also note that you have a shared `dataStream` for all connected clients, and when one client sends a `connectString`, the `dataStream` is replaced (again for all clients). But the event handlers for all other clients will be lost. I suggest you keep a `dataStream` per client instead (i.e., initialize it inside the `connection` handler.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize mine and Ben Taber's comments above, this solution might work better:

```
// Set up a connection to host and port, and emit on socket
function getDataStream(socket, port, host) {
    var dataStream = net.createConnection(port, host);

    dataStream.on('error', function(error){
        socket.emit('error',{message:"Data Connection Error "+ error});
    });

    dataStream.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('connected',{message:"Data Source Connected"});
    });

    dataStream.on('data', function(data) {  
        socket.emit('data', data);
    });

    return dataStream;
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var dataStream = getDataStream(socket, port, host);

    // Handle Client request to change stream 
    socket.on('message',function(data) {
        var clientMessage = JSON.parse(data);       
        if('connectString' in clientMessage
            && clientMessage.connectString.dataHost !== ''
            && clientMessage.connectString.dataPort !== '') {
            dataStream.end();
            dataStream = getDataStream(socket,
                clientMessage.connectString.dataPort,
                clientMessage.connectString.dataHost);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Many Thanks from a rookie!! That was the bone I needed.

Comment: Great! If the answer was to your satisfaction, please consider accepting it by clicking the big checkbox to the left of the answer.

Comment: How would I go about reconnecting dataStream in the event that the data on host:port quits. I tried putting a setTimeout in a dataStream.on('end',function(){setTimeout(function(){ dataStream.connect(port, host);},1000);}); This setTimeout does not seem to get activated when the host stops generating data on the port that dataStream is connected to.